# Passing Data from a Data class to a View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view

I'm studying MVVM and doing creating an app for practice

I was trying to make an app where you can add and view student's everything was ok until I tried to separate the Observable Collection from the rest of the ViewModel and be able to use it the other ViewModels.

My question is how to use an ObservableCollection or any other kind of data holder that is outside of any ViewModel in every View?

Tell me if you need code?

Here is the class with the data
in the solution explorer the path to the file is Data/Database

```
public class StudentDatabase
{
    #region Defining and Populating an ObservableCollection
    // Defining an observable collection to hold the students
    private ObservableCollection<Student> studentData;

    // Populating the ObservableCollection
   public StudentDatabase()
    {
        studentData = new ObservableCollection<Student>()
        {
            new Student(){Name="John", Surname="Smith", Age=17},
            new Student(){Name="Barbara", Surname="Johnson", Age=16}
        };
    }

    // Defining and setting the field for the Observable collection
    public ObservableCollection<Student> StudentData
    {
        get { return studentData;  }
        set { RaisePropertyChanged("studentData"); }
    }
    #endregion
    #region RaisePropertyChange implementation
    /// <summary>
    /// INotifyPropertyChanged implementation:
    /// A property notifies something that it has changed 
    /// and the other object get's the new data
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Here is the XAML of the page where I want to show it

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox DataContext="{Binding Path=Data.StudentDatabase}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding StudentData}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Name"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Surname"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Text="{Binding Surname}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Age"
                               Grid.Column="2"
                               Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

And search window c sharp code

```
public partial class Search: Window
{
    public Search()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I have this error in the output window in visual studio

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Data' property not found on 'object' ''StudentDatabase' (HashCode=2650314)'. BindingExpression:Path=Data.StudentDatabase; DataItem='StudentDatabase' (HashCode=2650314); target element is 'ListBox' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

I want the update of the list box to be dynamic so I do not include an Update button

EDIT: I've updated the code but I think I'm not doing something right again, could someone light me the way?

EDIT: If I set the DataContext in the codebehind everything is ok but if I try to set the DataContext onlt for the specific control in XAML then I don't get the list does not display the data

here is a link to [Skydrive](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=2006FCF483325549!5395&authkey=!AFODz6X7s3-I6tM&ithint=folder,) where I uploaded the project

if the codebehind is this everything works

```
InitializeComponent();
DataContext = new Data.StudentDatabase();
```

but if I don't use the codebehind and do it in XAML like this nothing happens

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=Data.StudentDatabase}"
```

I am obviously missing something here

Answer (score 1):

It is an application design issue. If you want share a collection with all the views, you need to put it inside the application view model, something like the `MainViewModel`. Also you need to be albe to access it from all the views, for doing this you may have a reference the `MainViewModel` in every view's view models that you want to show the collection. Another way is share the `MainViewModel` instance, you may save it in the application resources. If you use `Galasoft MVVMLight Toolkit` you may access the `MainViewModel` throught the `ViewModelLocator`. Hope this ideas helps...

---

**EDIT**
After adding your code, I can note that you are not understanding very well the `ViewModel` pattern. Your class `StudentObservableCollection` should be the `StudentViewModel`, and it should only have the student properties. Also you need to have a class for to manage the `StudentViewModel`s. In this class you should have the `StudentsData` or an `ObservableCollection<StudentViewModel>`, in this class also you may have other properties like `SelectedStudent` of type `StudentViewModel`. Like I said in my original answer, if the collection of students should be aviable on several views in the app, you may create it in a global view model.

Answer (score 0):

George,

If you are looking to share something like a database throughout your app, you can create the resource in your MainWindow and any controls defined under the visual tree of MainWindow will have access to that resource.

So in MainWindow XAML, do:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StudentDatabase x:Key="StudentDatabase"/>
<Window>Resources>
```

and in any controls after that, you can do something like `<ListBox DataContext="{StaticResource StudentDatabase}"/>` and that will use your StudentDatabase.

I would suggest making your Database static though, because every time you use  `{StaticResource StudentDatabase}` it will try to reinitialize that class.  Making it static you will be able to create one instance and use it throughout your application.

When you want to modify your database, in code-behind you can call something like `StudentDatabase sDB = (DataContext as StudentDatabase);` in an event, and you will be able to call your functions for modifying the db.

Consider this:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project"
    Title="Search" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StudentDatabase x:Key="StudentDatabase"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="StudentItemListBox"
             Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
             DataContext="{StaticResource StudentDatabase}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding StudentData}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}"
                                   Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"
                                   Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <!--Here go some other info about the students-->
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="Exit"
                <!--TO-DO: Write an exit command-->/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: And what happens if I want to use the AllStudents in other Views?

Comment: Then all you have to do is pass your instance of the `AllStudentsViewModel` object that was created, to your view.

Comment: That's the fun of learning MVVM and coming up with a good design. Once you create the object, you can hold on to it.  Then, based on the users actions, show a control and all you have to do is set the controls DataContext for it to fill with data.  You have to understand DataContext to continue with MVVM or more importantly WPF.

Comment: So I don't need to set the DataContext for the whole View but only the control. And is there a problem if I create a different class for holding the data and use it as a DataContext insted of putting the Data in one of the ViewModels

Comment: There isn't a problem with that. That would be kind of like how a database works... You store your data, then when you need it you go get it (which is called getting the Context) and would display the data.

Comment: and if the Data class in in a folder do I need to point the whole path or just the name of the Data class

Comment: Chances are that your namespace is making it seem like you need the whole path.  If you create a new folder and add a new class by right clicking on that folder, your namespace for that class will inherit the path of that folder.  So if you have `MyProjects` as your project and you create a `Data` folder under it, when you create a class under that folder your namespace for that class will be `MyProjects.Data` for that class. If you change the namespace for all your classes to be the same, you won't need to use a "path"

Comment: the path to the class is Data/Database, the class name is Database, the name of the collection is StudentData. I'm using this line of code: 'DataContext ="{Binding Path=Data/Database, Source=StudentData}"', Am I doing something wrong again or what? at the initial start of the window the data does not load and I want it to be loaded on startup. NOTE: I've updated the code in case you need to look at it

Comment: Try, `DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentData}"` for ListBox, watch your Output windows for any binding errors. Post any binding errors you get.

Comment: I did try to use the way you told me but I don't seem to make it work, I made a simpler project and I will update the code and post the output later. Thank you for your time and help so far.

Comment: Feel free to join the WPF chat for any help http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf

Comment: I do not have the reputation to join in but thanks for the invite

Comment: You should be able to now.

Comment: Yes I am but what happend

Comment: I am sorry but I am still unable to chat, the system sent me a notification that I could use the chat system but when I click your link the 'need 20 reputation' warning is still there. I don't know what to do

Comment: I do not know where to post the link so I'll put it in the first post

Comment: You can type anything you want into chat. You might need to refresh page.